# Play classpath in usable form?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

How can I get the CLASSPATH used by Play 1.2.x in a form that's actually directly usable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
play classpath|tr ',' '\n'|tail -n +10|sed -ne "s|^.*'\([^']*\)'.*$|\1|p"|tr '\n' ':'
```